# Restore an Oracle database to another disk drive in Windows Server 2012

Tags: database, oracle

My question is about the following, it is required to pass a database of Oracle Database 10g Express Edition to 11g. I was given the backup on a pendrive, it is a file with extension .dmp (Dump file).

I installed the 11g Express Edition on a new server but also installed the database that comes with this (XE).

I want to restore the database from the 10g to another unit other than C, which is where the Oracle 11g database is installed. I also want this new database to "replace" the XE (I do not know if it is the correct way to say it).

I have only found adjustments and location changes but only within the same unit.

Any scope would be very useful.

Thank you.

Comment: you can use expdp / impdp to export import your database. does this fits to you?

Comment: How would I do if I only have the backup on a pendrive? What would be the procedure to be able to restore it according to what I indicate?

Comment: what did you for backing up your data? how did you backup?

Comment: I do not know exactly, I only received the file directly on a pendrive from another institution to be able to restore it on our servers. It is a single file with extension .dmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the comments, it sounds like you have been given a Database Dump file (`.dmp`) from a database on a pendrive, and you need to figure out how to get that file into a database, correct?

First, let's go over some background. What is a dump file (`.dmp`)? From [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_export.htm#g1022624):

> The dump file set is made up of one or more disk files that contain
>   table data, database object metadata, and control information. The
>   files are written in a proprietary, binary format. During an import
>   operation, the Data Pump Import utility uses these files to locate
>   each database object in the dump file set.

At a high level, that `.dmp` file is a collection of `DDL` and `DML` statements that will recreate whatever data and objects that were exported. `.dmp` files make it easier to transport and move large amounts of data between databases using Data Pump. But what is [Data Pump](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_overview.htm#g1015896)? Again, from Oracle:

> Oracle Data Pump technology enables very high-speed movement of data and metadata from one database to another.

Basically, Data Pump is a set of utilities (`EXPDP` & `IMPDP`) that are used to move data between databases. The `.dmp` file you have was likely created using `EXPDP`. You will need to use `IMPDP` to import that `.dmp` file into a database.

Here's were it gets interesting - you say that you already have an 11g database, correct? If you want to, you should be able to import the 10g dump file directly into your 11g database without any issues. The reason is that Oracle tends to be backwards compatible, and ***typically* speaking**, anything that you do with one version of Oracle will be compatible with the version that immediately succeeds it. Jumping from something like Oracle 8i to 11g won't work, but you can always go from 8i to 9i, from 9i to 10g, and so on.

If you want to import that dump file into your 11g database, here's what you'll need to do:

1. Create a DBA account, or have an account that has been granted Data Pump privileges explicitly.
2. Move the .dmp file to the server where your 11g database lives. If you want to make it even easier for yourself, you can move the .dmp file to your database's datapump directory. If you don't know where that is, execute the following query on your database: `select * from all_directories where directory_name = 'DATA_PUMP_DIR';` This query will return a directory. You don't have to use this directory, it will just make it easier.
3. Once you have the dump file in place and you have all of the necessary database and operating system privileges, you are ready to import the dmp file. Open a new command line window, set your Oracle home if it is not already set, and then navigate to the directory where you placed the .dmp file. Your import command will look something like this:

   impdp [USERNAME]/[PASSWORD]@[DATABASE] directory=[DIRECTORY] dumpfile=[FILENAME].dmp logfile=[LOGFILE].log

   Where `[USERNAME]`/`[PASSWORD]` are your credentials, `[DATABASE]` is the name of the database you're importing the dump file into, `[DIRECTORY]` is whatever directory you placed the dump file in, `[FILENAME]` is the name of the .dmp file, and `[LOGFILE]` is whatever name you chose for your log file.

Assuming your database has everything necessary for the .dmp file, the import should begin and you will start seeing status updates that look similar to this:

```
Starting [USERNAME]."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01":  [USERNAME]/******** directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=[FILENAME].dmp logfile=[LOGFILE].log 
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/USER
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SYSTEM_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/ROLE_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
```

Note that this is just an example, your results may look different. Assuming all goes well, you will see a message like this at the end:

```
Job [USERNAME]."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" completed
```

If you don't want to import it into your existing 11g database, you could always spin up a new database and import the .dmp file to that one using these same guidelines.

That should be enough to get you started down the right path, hope this helps and good luck!

P.S. Here is a great FAQ on the Data Pump utilities as well: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Import_Export_FAQ

Comment: Thanks, I could not use your recommendation for the import because the export was done with the exp and not with the expdp. So I used imp I had an inconvenience on the way, but I suppose it will be a topic for another forum.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it spot on, but I'm glad I could help you get started in the right direction. Kind of odd that they used imp over impdp, but if they were using a 10g instance, I'm guessing they were just using the same scripts they always have. Glad you got it figured out! Make sure you keep a record of the command(s) you used as well, just in case you have to do another import like this in the future.

Comment: Thanks to you, I hope you help me with my next problem, it is linked to this issue and the location of the restored files.

Comment: Well, I can't make any promises but I can definitely give it a shot. By the location of the stored files, do you mean the location of the database files that actually hold the data, or something else entirely? Post a link to the question here and I will give it a look when I have some time.

Comment: Thank you! I already published my question, this is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54202921/change-the-tablespace-of-the-destination-when-restoring-a-database-in-oracle-11g