# Change the TABLESPACE of the destination when restoring a database in Oracle 11g (Windows Server 2012 R2)

Tags: database, oracle, backup, restore

I was doing an import of a database *(schema)* from a previous version *(Oracle 10g express editon)* to a more recent version *(Oracle 11g express edition)* in Oracle from a `.dmp` file *(I did not export, I was only responsible for make the import into the new environment)*, the way to do it I consulted in a previous forum and I managed to import using `imp`, I could not use the `impdp` because the export was not done with the `expdp`.

Well, once the restoration was done what I needed most was to restore all the objects in another tablespace, for that I had previously created a user, a tablespace associated with that user and naturally a datafile associated with that tablespace. But all the objects had been restored within the system tablespace (`USERS`), since in the source database these are in that tablespace.

The instruction that I used and thought would help me was the following:

```
imp my_user/password@XE FILE=C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\admin\XE\dpdump\my_file.dmp FROMUSER=my_user TOUSER=my_user
```

However, even though I tried to change the user (`FR0MUSER` and `TOUSER`), the data is still restored in the `USERS` tablespace and also in `SYSTEM`.

I guess the only way to solve this is to export again. I have three options: The `exp`, `expdp` and the `RMAN`. Although I am not sure that these help me alone to change or modify the destination tablespace.

Any reference would be very helpful.

Comment: Are you looking at re-exporting from the original source data (or getting whoever used `exp` to redo it with `expdp`)? Or are you looking at exporting from your new database just so you can re-import with `remap_tablespace` (dropping all objects for your user in between) ? Or do you just want to re-import again from your existing dump file but into your preferred tablespace (dropping all objects for your user first)?

Comment: Hi Alex, I worked with Fran on the previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54076478/restore-an-oracle-database-to-another-disk-drive-in-windows-server-2012/). I think Fran wants to move the objects associated with that schema (FR0MUSER) to a different tablespace within the database. I would suggest using EXPDP/IMPDP for that, it's just much easier in my experience.

Comment: At the moment I was thinking of doing the export from the same server (oracle 11g), but I do not know if it is an option to use the exp. To achieve the change of tablespace would create a manual for the person in charge of the backup of the environment in oracle 10g to do the same. Thank you for your answers AlexPoole  and  cdb_dba.

Comment: Use EXPDP over EXP! It is more robust, and quite frankly, easier to use. Once the data is in the database, you can use whatever tool you prefer to export it. If you are in contact with the person/team that produced the original export, you can always ask them to use EXPDP from now on, but your mileage may vary as some organizations are resistant to change. It's worth a shot, but don't expect them to change their processes just for you, especially if it is an outside organization.

Comment: As well `expdp` being more robust and easier to user, `exp` [is desupported as of 11g](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_export.htm). Your first use case - importing a file created in 10g with `exp` - is kind of OK, but you shouldn't then use it to export *from* 11g. And you should encourage whoever is doing the 10g export to move to `expdp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify, you have already completed an import and the data has been loaded into the database, however, the imported objects were loaded into the Users and System tablespaces, rather than the tablespace you created for them, correct?

There are a number of ways to do this, such as using the [DBMS_REDEFINITION](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_redefi.htm#CBBJJAIF) package or issuing commands like `ALTER TABLE [SCHEMA].[TABLE] MOVE TABLESPACE [NEW TABLESPACE]`, however that can be extremely tedious, and may present problems if the database is in use. You would have to rebuild the indexes, and you would also have to move the lob files.

I would recommend using data pump (`EXPDP`) to create a new export of the schema, then remap the tablespaces while re-importing it into the database. Your steps would follow this general outline:

1. Export the schema using a command similar to this: `expdp [user]/[pass] SCHEMAS=[SCHEMA] DIRECTORY=DATA_PUMP_DIR DUMPFILE=Export.dmp LOGFILE=export.log`, where [SCHEMA] is the name of the schema that you want to remap. You can use any directory, dumpfile, and logfile name you want - this is just an example.
2. You'll want to drop the schema before re-importing it. Make sure to use the cascade option so that all of the objects are dropped: `DROP USER [SCHEMA] CASCADE;`
3. Finally, you can re-import the schema and use the REMAP_TABLESPACE clause to remap the objects to your desired tablespace:  `impdp [user]/[pass] SCHEMAS=[SCHEMA] REMAP_TABLESPACE=SYSTEM:[TABLESPACE] REMAP_TABLESPACE=USERS:[TABLESPACE] DIRECTORY=DATA_PUMP_DIR DUMPFILE=Export.dmp LOGFILE=import.log`, where [TABLESPACE] is the tablespace you created for the schema.

Assuming all goes well, the schema will be re-imported into the database, and the objects of that schema that were originally mapped to the `USERS` and `SYSTEM` tablespaces will be remapped to your `[TABLESPACE]`.

Comment: The export was made correctly until the following error message appeared:

ORA-39171: Job is experiencing a resume wait.
ORA-01658: unable to create INITIAL extent for segment in tablespace MY_TABLESPACE

 I had to cancel the process (ctrl + c), the window was left with the following command "import>".

I understand that these considerations have to be taken into account at the time of creating the tablespace.

Comment: The `import>` prompt is still part of the data pump utility. Before starting any import, you should ensure that there is enough table space available. If there is ample tablespace, don't forget to also check the disk storage of the server/system, as the space dedicated to a tablespace isn't really "taken" until the extent is allocated. Once the tablespace issue is solved, you can always reattach to the datapump job and resume it manually with a command like `impdp [user]/[pass] ATTACH=[JOB_NAME]` and then issuing `START_JOB` (you can use `SELECT * FROM dba_datapump_jobs;` to get the JOB_NAME)

Comment: Yes, I did that. I created an extendable auto tablespace and followed the steps to resume the job. Thank you very much for the help provided.

Comment: Happy to help, and glad I could be of assistance :)

Answer (score 1):

As you've already imported everything, you could move all the tables and indexes to your preferred tablespace with [`alter table`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_1010.htm) and [`alter index`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_3001.htm) commands, e.g.:

```
alter table my_table move tablespace my_tablespace;
alter index my_index rebuild tablespace my_tablespace;
```

You can use the data dictionary to generate those statements, with something like:

```
select 'alter table "' || object_name || '" move tablespace my_tablespace;'
from user_objects
where object_type = 'TABLE';

select 'alter index "' || object_name || '" rebuild tablespace my_tablespace;'
from user_objects
where object_type = 'INDEX';
```

with the output written to a script you then run; or you could use similar queries and dynamic SQL to do it all in one go.

There may be edge cases you need to deal with - maybe additional steps for partitions, and I'm not sure if IOTs will cause problems, but that might get you started - and at least reduce the amount of re-export/re-import you need to do.

Of course, you need enough space for both the old and new tablespaces to move the objects, as they'll exist in both as they move - one at a time, but may still be an issue too...